# Be able select object in UIpageControl

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

Im in the middle of a college project and Im new to iphone development by 3 weeks and I want my app to have a UIPageControl full with a deck of cards and the user selects a card and it is placed to a designated area on the screen. It would be similar to the National Lottery app the way the all the balls in the UiPageControl and you can select one and it goes to a designated area. All I need to know is how to do it not the code. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A UIPageControl are just the little dots you would see on SpingBoard. I think yiu are wanting a UIScrollView.

See the documentation  'http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html'

```
EDIT:
```

Check out this example on how to use a UIScrollView & a UIPageControl together. You can tap to the left and right of the dots to move the page in either direction.

[UIScrollView + UIPageControll](http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/09/26/uipagecontrol-uiscrollview/)

Comment: Ya that's what I want but how could u select an item in the page and then have it automatically placed on the main view?

Comment: [scroller addSubview:yourObject];

Comment: No I want a UIPageControl the scroll view moves the entire screen yes?

Comment: You are going to need a UIScrollView to "move the screen" You will hook the UIPageControl up to it to let you know what page you are on, but it's not as easy as that. Let me edit with example.

Comment: I haven't it started yet iv left this option till last in the app and don't know where to start I know what I want but don't know how to do it, its basically same concept as The Irish National Lottery app on the itunes store could you look at it and see if you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ya thats the page movement i want but want to have multiple objects in each page and a user selects one then from a page and it disappears from that page an is placed in a designated area?

Answer (score 0):

So you are basically looking for a SpringBoard type feature?

Then check out [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20), specifically the `Launcher` class.